# 403 Error when trying to deploy a S3 policy using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to deploy a static website using an S3 bucket with Terraform.

Therefore I need to use the a `aws_s3_bucket_policy` resource:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version   = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "PublicReadGetObject"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = "*"
        Action    = "s3:GetObject"
        Resource  = [
          aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn,
          "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}/*",
        ]
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

When I try to deploy this I get the following error:

`Error: putting S3 policy: AccessDenied: Access Denied`

Comment: Looks like you the credentials you are using do not have sufficient permissions

Comment: I double checked the permissions. To make sure everything works I tried a run using a user with admin principles.

Answer (score 2):

AWS has changed default permissions for new buckets in April this year. Since then public access is fully restricted by default, so you are not able to put your access policy without enabling proper option. You can try to use this Terraform resource, to unblock public policies:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "example"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id

  block_public_policy     = false // This is default, so you can probably remove this line
  restrict_public_buckets = false // same as above
  block_public_acls       = true 
  ignore_public_acls      = true 
}
```

This will probably overwrite default bucket settings. I think that you will also need to use `depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.example ]` in policy resource to make sure that those options will be changed before terraform attach policy to bucket.

Comment: I had the same issue as the original poster and this solution fixed the problem for me, The only difference is that I'm using`terraform import` on an existing s3 bucket hosting a static website.

Answer (score 0):

since the s3 bucket exists already, the PutBucketPolicy needs to be assigned for the user or role being used:

1. in iam: add a policy that grants the appropriate permissions for the user or role being used.
2. s3 bucket policy: add a policy that grants the appropriate permissions for the user or role being used.

the 2nd item isn't needed unless the bucket policy restricts bucket policy updates.

if you can view the bucket policy, you can see who has the appropriate permissions to update the bucket policy.  if not active user or role has access to update the bucket policy, you'll need to use the aws account root user to update the bucket policy to grant an active user the update the bucket policy.